# JS - Canvas - Полупрозрачные линии

Tags: javascript, canvas

На канвасе рисую два контура прямоугольника непрозрачным цветом. В двух местах прямоугольники пересекаются, и по идее, второй(верхний) прямоугольник должен перекрывать первый(нижний), но их контуры почему то смешиваются.

```js
const c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.strokeRect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
ctx.strokeRect(50,50,200,200);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отрисовывай свои однопиксельные линии в координатах вроде `ctx.lineTo(10.5, 10.5)`. Рисование однопиксельных линий в координатах `(10, 10)` значит, что этот `1` пиксель находится в координатах с `9.5` до `10.5`, что приводит к рисованию двух линий на канвасе.

Интересный способ не прибавлять каждый раз `0.5` к настоящим координатам, если много однописксельных линий, использовать `ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5)` в самом начале.

<sub>перевод ответа [@allan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279863/2881286)</sub>

```js
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.strokeStyle = "gray";
ctx.strokeRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Answer (score 3):

Антиалиасин

```js
const c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth=10;
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.strokeRect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
ctx.strokeRect(50,50,200,200);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Comment: А можно както победить антиалиасин если мне нужна линия в 1px?